# Finding the PDF that maximizes the $\alpha$-th moment

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Given $\alpha$ and constant $\mu$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \displaystyle\int_0^\infty p(x)x^\alpha \,\mathrm d x\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\int_0^\infty p(x)\,\mathrm d x = 1\\ & \displaystyle\int_0^\infty p(x)x \, \mathrm d x = \mu\end{array}$$

Comment: What do you mean by optimize? Do you want one $p$ for all $\alpha$, or is $\alpha$ given?

Comment: For a given value of $\alpha$, what maximizes the integral.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ integer or, could it take on arbitrary real values?  In what range?

Comment: Arbitrary real value

Comment: Have you heard of Langrange-Multipliers?